# Replacing dataframe value given multiple condition from another dataframe with R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, dataset, data-manipulation

I have two dataframes one with the dates (converted in months) of multiple survey replicates for a given grid cell and the other one with snow data for each month for the same grid cell, they have a matching ID column to identify the cells.
What I would like to do is to replace in the first dataframe, the one with months of survey replicates, the month value with the snow value for that month considering the grid cell ID.
Thank you

```
CellID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
sampl1 <- c("oct", "oct", "oct", "nov", NA, NA)
sampl2 <- c("nov", "nov", "jan", NA, NA, NA)
sampl3 <- c("dec", "dec", "jan", NA, NA, NA)
df1 <- data.frame(CellID, sampl1, sampl2, sampl3)
print(df1)

CellID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
oct <- c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
nov <- c(0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5)
dec <- c(0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.8)
df2 <- data.frame(CellID, oct, nov, dec)
print(df2)

CellID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
sampl1_snow <- c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, NA, NA)
sampl2_snow <- c(0.4, 0.5, 0.9, NA, NA, NA)
sampl3_snow <- c(0.6, 0.7, 1, NA, NA, NA)
df3 <- data.frame(CellID, sampl1_snow, sampl2_snow, sampl3_snow)
print(df3)
```

Comment: (1) Your example data is missing a `jan` column. (2) The values for `jan` are inconsistent, since it's `0.9` and `1` both in row 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      starts_with("sampl"),
      ~imap_dbl(.x, ~ifelse(is.null(df2[.y, .x]), NA_real_, df2[.y, .x])),
      .names = "{.col}_snow"
      ),
    .keep = "unused"
    )
```

to get

```r
  CellID sampl1_snow sampl2_snow sampl3_snow
1      1         0.1         0.4         0.6
2      2         0.1         0.5         0.7
3      3         0.1         0.9         0.9
4      4         0.5          NA          NA
5      5          NA          NA          NA
6      6          NA          NA          NA
```

### Data

For `df2` I used

```r
structure(list(CellID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), oct = c(0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), nov = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5), dec = c(0.6, 
0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.8), jan = c(0, 0, 0.9, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: @akrun It's `is.null`. Subsetting the data.frame with non-existent columns returns `NULL`. But I actually don't understand, why this works here since we basically do `df2[3, NA]` which fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
df3 <- df1
df3[!is.na(df1)] <- df2[!is.na(df1)]
#   CellID sampl1 sampl2 sampl3
# 1      1    0.1    0.4    0.6
# 2      2    0.1    0.5    0.7
# 3      3    0.1    0.4    0.8
# 4      4    0.1   <NA>   <NA>
# 5      5   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 6      6   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `match`

```
df1[-1] <- df2[-1][cbind(df1$CellID[col(df1[-1])], 
         match(as.matrix(df1[-1]), names(df2)[-1]))]
```